# How to make an onchange event for a asp:textbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning javascript but new to jQuery and am trying to make an on change event handeler for all the text boxes in my document. So here is my Text box

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3" runat="server">
                        <asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableCell BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" BackColor="Blue" runat="server" Width="40" Text="1" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
```

And My script at the bottom

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="vehicle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Than my javascript.

```
$("textbox").change(function () {
 alert("ggg");
});
```

But when i change the text inside my textbox it will not alert
I know how to make a regular javascript event but i want to be able to make a event to fire for all textboxes.

Comment: You need to use the keyup or keydown even for textboxes; .change() is for a drop-down selector.

Comment: @frenchie That's not true.

Comment: @Nit: well that's what I use and it works; I'm sure there's more to it but keyup on textboxes works for me.

Comment: As per the actual question, an asp:TextBox is not rendered as a node with that name, find out what it's actually rendered as and bind to that.

Comment: @frenchie: That does not work. In fact It works in other projects i just can't  figure out how to do it in jQuery

Comment: When using the change event in JQuery, it does not take effect until the input loses focus (for inputs).  Keyup fires as soon as a key bounces back up after it goes down.  The change event should work here, but as @nit pointed out, the selector doesn't look quite right.  If you wanted it to fire on all inputs, you could use `$("input").change(function...`, but you'd be better off selecting by class or id:  `$("#MyElementId")` or `$(".MyElementClass")`

Comment: @DennisHertzler: there might be other issues with your code but here's a jsfiddle that does what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/o7ar46ne/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fugured out my issue. It was a novice error. i'm sorry. I had a wrong src script to my document. I had been working with another page a copyed the script tag over and forgot to change the src.

Answer (score 3):

Asp:textbox is render like input type=text, so your selector will need to be:

```
 $('input[type=text]')
```

But don't use that one, cause it will bind all the text input's in your page, use the id of the element, also use keypress()

```
 $('#TextBox1').keypress(  function() {  alert(); });
```

Comment: Did not work  (I need The event to fire when any of the textboxes are changed

Comment: Just noticed that you are setting TextMode=number, so your selector for all the textbox should be 
$('input[type=numbert]'), but to be sure to select just the ones insde the table use $('#Table1 input[type=numbert]')

Comment: sorry that did't work. I also tryed imput[type=number]

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it will help

```js
    
        $('#some_id').on('keyup', function() {
             $('#entered_val').text(this.value);// or $(this).val()
        });
```

```html
    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <input type='text' id='some_id' name='textbox'/>
        <span id='entered_val'></span>
```

Comment: I repeat I know how to make a event handeler in javascript to fire on one textbox but i want a event handeler to fire on all textboxes!!